# oracle cursor open-for-using giving wrong result

Tags: oracle, plsql

code 1:

```
OPEN P_CURSOR FOR V_STR_SQL2
        USING P_USER_ID, P_USER_ID, V_NODEID, V_PROCID, V_ADDRESSE;
```

output : 0,0,0,0

when i change this code to :

```
 V_STR_SQL2 := replace(V_STR_SQL2,':P_USER_ID',P_USER_ID);
   V_STR_SQL2 := replace(V_STR_SQL2,':V_NODEID',V_NODEID);
   V_STR_SQL2 := replace(V_STR_SQL2,':V_PROCID',V_PROCID);
   V_STR_SQL2 := replace(V_STR_SQL2,':V_ADDRESSE',V_ADDRESSE);
 OPEN P_CURSOR FOR V_STR_SQL2;
```

output : 1,0,0,0

second output is correct. what could be the reason? any idea?
datatype of bind variables are as below.

1. userid varchar2, input
2. nodeid,procid, number(10)
3. address   varchar2(250);

> -- Edited

When I debug my stored proc, this is the value of v_str_sql2 before executing open cursor. When I run this query by giving its vlaue in sqldeveloper it gives me correct result. but wrong result with open-for-using.

```
SELECT COUNT(DECODE(ZC.STATUS, NULL, 1)) "NEW",
   COUNT(DECODE(ZC.STATUS, 'KEEP', 1)) "KEEP",
   COUNT(DECODE(ZC.STATUS, 'LOCK', 1)) "LOCK",
   COUNT(DECODE(ZC.STATUS,
                'KEEP',
                DECODE(UPPER(ZC.STATUS_BY), UPPER(:P_USER_ID), 1))) "PKEEP",
   COUNT(DECODE(ZC.STATUS,
                'LOCK',
                DECODE(UPPER(ZC.STATUS_BY), UPPER(:P_USER_ID), 1))) "PLOCK"
  FROM tab1 PARTITION(DCL_OTHERS) DCL,
   tab2      ZC,
   tab3      TC
 WHERE DCL.NODE_ID = TC.NODE_ID
   AND DCL.PROC_ID = TC.PROC_ID
   AND DCL.CASE_REF_NO = TC.CLAIM_REF_NO
   AND DCL.NODE_ID = ZC.NODE_ID(+)
   AND DCL.PROC_ID = ZC.PROC_ID(+)
   AND DCL.CASE_NAME = ZC.CASENUM(+)
   AND DCL.USER_NAME = ZC.USERNAME(+)
   AND DCL.NODE_ID = :V_NODEID
   AND (DCL.PROC_ID = :V_PROCID)
   AND (1 = 1)
   AND DCL.USER_NAME = :V_ADDRESSE
```

> Edit 2

I am using this syntax. Is that something wrong with this syntax?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_HTH_QUEUEPAGE(P_QUEUENAME VARCHAR2,
                                              P_CURSOR    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                              P_REC_CNT   OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  -- CODE TO GENERATE DYNAMIC SQL
  OPEN P_CURSOR FOR V_STR_SQL1
    USING V_ADDRESSE, V_NODEID, V_PROCID, V_STATUS, V_USER_ID, P_EP, P_SP;
  /*END IF;*/
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_STR_SQL2
    INTO P_REC_CNT
    USING V_NODEID, V_PROCID, V_USER_ID, V_STATUS, V_ADDRESSE;
END;
```

Comment: Not knowing what your query is, the relationship between the two code snippets, anything about your data, any idea what the output represents, etc. it is very hard to speculate.  If you post the SQL statement, we'd at least have something to work with.  If you post a simple test case that we can run on our machines, you'll almost certainly get an answer.

Comment: Hi Justin Cave.. Any observations? Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I wouldn't normally expect the query to work after `replace(V_STR_SQL2,':P_USER_ID',P_USER_ID)`; if `P_USER_ID` is a string, the query will now treat the *value* of that string as a column name, usually leading to ORA_00904. That doesn't seem to be happening, so wonder if it's a number with whitespace. Unfortunately that doesn't appear to be relevant to the problem... unless `V_NODEID` or `V_PROCID` are varchars. Which you said isn't the case.

Comment: Correct. And as you said, I do not prefer to write     replace(V_STR_SQL2,':P_USER_ID',P_USER_ID); But my code is not working with USING. Hence I am left with only this option. :(

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the below

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_STR_SQL2
INTO P_REC_CNT
USING  V_USER_ID,V_USER_ID,V_NODEID,V_PROCID, V_ADDRESSE;
```

The below link would give you more idea why

[Dynamic SQL Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/dynamic.htm)

Answer (score 0):

What concerns me is this line here:

```
V_STR_SQL2 := replace(V_STR_SQL2,':V_ADDRESSE',V_ADDRESSE);
```

This puts the contents of the `VARCHAR2` variable `V_ADDRESSE` directly into the query, without any quoting.

Given the value of `V_STR_SQL2` you obtained during debugging, the value of `V_ADDRESSE` must be something that is a valid SQL expression.  If its value was something like `1 High Street`, you would end up with `V_STR_SQL2` containing something like

```
AND DCL_USER_NAME = 1 High Street
```

which isn't valid SQL.  You'd get an error attempting to execute this.

So, what could `V_ADDRESSE` contain?  Two possibilities suggest themselves to me:

- The value of your variable `V_ADDRESSE` contains a `'` at either end, such as `'1 High Street'`.
- The value of your variable `V_ADDRESSE` contains a string such as `00012493` and you want this to match a value `12493`.

What exactly does `V_ADDRESSE` contain?